# NonRepeatableRequestException while sending image to server

Tags: android, http

from time to time (especially when I have a bad connection) I obtain `NonRepeatableRequestException` while
sending image to server. Here is my code:

```
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();

SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
       registry.register(new Scheme("http",
PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));

DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new
ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry), params);

HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uri);
SimpleMultipartEntity multipartContent = new SimpleMultipartEntity();
multipartContent.addPart(propName, filename, inputStream,
contentType);
httpPost.setEntity(multipartContent);
httpclient.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.expect-continue",
false);

java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("httpclient.wire.header").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.FINEST);
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("httpclient.wire.content").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.FINEST);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
```

I realized that InputStream is non-repeatable type, but have no idea how to create request properly and avoid this exception.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found that I can add my own DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler for my httpclient:

```
httpclient.setHttpRequestRetryHandler(new DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler(3, false) {

    public boolean retryRequest(IOException exception, int executionCount,
            HttpContext context) {
             if (executionCount > this.getRetryCount()) {
                return false;
            }
             if (exception != null) {
                 return true;
             } else {
                 return super.retryRequest(exception, executionCount, context);
             }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found one of the reasons for this exception to be raised.

According to [this group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/rest-assured/mgZNEin6kjU) this exception may be raised because the server is returning HTTP 401 (Unauthorized).